# Spring- load applicationContext from jar file

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jar, applicationcontext

I would like to load applicationContext from a jar file(common-1.0.jar). I used this steps in stand alone application,

in pom file:

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.cityid</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

After that I use:

```
    private static BeanFactory factory = null;
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
    new String[] {"spring/mainContext.xml"});
    factory = (BeanFactory) appContext;
    PartyFacade partyFacade = (PartyFacade) factory.getBean("partyFacade");
    //Party party = new PartyFacade(); //Entity
    partyFacade.fillParty();
```

I can load PartyFacadeBean but i cant load and new Entities such as Party it throw nullpoint exception! this approach just work for Beans it doesn't work for DAO Or Entity.    how to new entity and and fill them in stand alone applicatin?

Comment: If spring is able to lookup partyFacade from mainContext.xml then other bean definitions should also be visible in this file. **But I can;t load and new entities** be more dscriptive here to help us understand the problem. Sample code and error trace also required.

Comment: This is probably about **component-scan** inside JAR file. Am I correct?

Comment: @Pavel: component-Scan don't have problem becuse all of may class placed in same directory.

Comment: @Himanshu: if i want to use classes of jar file in a standalone spring application that does not have  tomcat or any application server what should I do? I use junit for test and runned true but i can't run it main class !

Comment: If you are trying to load application context, it is not a necessity to have container like tomcat. They way you are loading bean defs in the above question looks fine. If you are having trouble running from main class, you should be facing some exception, paste it and we can look.

Comment: You need to call `appContext.refresh()` by the way if you are loading context manually.